# How much Gas Token used in total Gas?

Tags: gas, cpp-ethereum, ethereum-classic, mint, burn

Users can Mint Gas tokens at a lower price and Free them when the Gas price is high in Ethereum.

In Etherscan, the available information is Gas Used. There is no more information about how much Gas is used from their already mint Gas Tokens.  (Total Gas Used = Gas + Gas token)

Is there any way to decompose the Gas used and find the amount used from the Gas token?

Thank you